# where clause on 'insert into select' not filtering records

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, insert-into

I am writing a query where I use an `INSERT INTO tablename SELECT` statement, and end the `INSERT INTO` statement with a `where` clause. However, the `where` is not filtering the results as intended (I know there are records where this criteria is not met and should be filtered out), nor is it throwing an error. So, I cannot figure out why it is not outputting the expected results.

Please see my code below:

```
N'INSERT INTO table
 SELECT DISTINCT
      [Identifier]
      ,[Variable1]
      ,[Variable2]
      ,[Variable3]
      ,[Variable4]
      ,[Variable5]
      ,[Variable6]
      ,[Variable7]
      ,[Variable8]
      ,NULL
      ,[Variable9]
      ,NULL
  FROM [DBname].[tablename].[tablename2]
WHERE [Variable10] = ''Successful'';'
```

Comment: Can you put sample data? Also, can you run the SELECT query (without the INSERT) and check if what you suspect is correct?

Comment: can't provide sample data. i have run the SELECT query without the INSERT and gotten the correct results.

Comment: Because when I run the query with and without the 'where clause' I get the same number of records. There should be a number of records excluded from the results using the 'where clause' and that is not happening.

Comment: Are you sure your table name is correct? [DBname].[tablename].[tablename2]

Comment: Are you sure about your from statement? As SQL Server will throw an Invalid object name error.

Comment: Basically the insert into is irrelevant to this question. Why is your SQL statement surrounded by quotes? If you add `Variable10` to the list of select  columns what do you see?

Comment: table name is correct. from statement is correct - it all works without 'where' clause. i am creating a new table, hence insert into. When I add Variable10 into the new table and then into SELECT statement, it throws an error that i have an unclosed quotation mark and cuts off tablename2, evidently not running successfully.

Answer (score 3):

A free beer says your variable is a VARCHAR(300) and this is 340 characters long, truncating it right before the WHERE clause.

Comment: Plus one for the wit.

Comment: I don't have permission to view the length of variable10 (since I did not declare it), so I can't figure out how to alter the length of it either.

Comment: AH - you mean the size of the INSERT INTO statement. you were right. It was 5000 characters long, and I guess the where clause was a bit longer....

Comment: I owe you a beer!

Comment: It was only easy for me to spot because I've done so many times myself!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your table name is correct? (`[DBname].[tablename].[tablename2]`)

Are you sure your table structure that insert is correct?

```
Declare @sql varchar(4000)
Set @sql =N'
    INSERT INTO [TITMS_Test].[dbo].[GROUP] (Name, Description)
    SELECT DISTINCT Name, Description
    FROM [TITMS].[dbo].[GROUP]
    WHERE [Name] = ''Imported'';'
Print @sql
Exec (@sql)
```

Comment: yes- everything works perfectly except for the 'where' clause.